# Can't pass values to or from Python using JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I am trying to pass values from a website to Python, and get a return passed back to be displayed. The input location is as follows:

```
<form>                                                                      <!-- create inputs -->
    <input type="text" id="WS" style="font-size:10pt; height:25px" required><br>    <!-- Wind speed input box -->
<br>
</form>
```

The user then clicks a button (in this case Lin):

```html
<button id="Lin" style="height:30px; width:10%; background-color:#5188e0; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold" title="Linear regression attempts to model the relationship between two variables by fitting a linear equation to observed data">Linear Regression</button>
```

This should pass the data to the following script:

```
$("#Lin").click(
    function(e) {
        $.get('/api/Lin/' + $('#WS').val(), function(data) {
            $('#Power_Est').val(data.value);
        });
    });
```

The output box is:

```html
<form>
    <label>Estimated power output (KW/h):</label>                           <!-- Power label -->
    <input class="form-control" id="Power_Est" type="text" style="font-size:10pt; height:25px" placeholder="Power Estimate" readonly><br>   <!-- Power Estimate box -->
    <br>
</form>
```

The Python script I have is:

```py
import flask as fl
import numpy as np
import joblib

app = fl.Flask(__name__)                                        # Create a new web app.

@app.route("/")                                                 # Add root route.
def home():                                                     # Home page
    return app.send_static_file("Front_Page.html")              # Return the index.html file

@app.route("/api/Lin/<float:speed>", methods = ["GET"])         # If the Linear Regression button is chosen
def Lin_Reg(speed):                                             # Call the linear regression function
    lin_model_load = joblib.load("Models/lin_reg.pkl")          # Reimport the linear regression model
    power_est = np.round(lin_model_load.predict(speed)[0], 3)   # Use the linear regression model to estimate the power for the user inputted speed
    return power_est                                            # Return the power estimate
```

Whenever I run the above, using flask, and http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I get the following error message:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 21:07:19] "GET /api/Lin/20 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

**Edit 1**

Using the below:

```py
def Lin_Reg(speed):                                             # Call the linear regression function
    print(speed)
    speed = speed.reshape(1, -1)
    lin_model_load = joblib.load("Models/lin_reg.pkl")          # Reimport the linear regression model
    power_est = lin_model_load.predict(speed) # Use the linear regression model to estimate the power for the user inputted speed
    return power_est                                            # Return the power estimate

print(Lin_Reg(20.0))
```

The error is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 6     return power_est                                            # Return the power estimate
> 7
> ----> 8 print(Lin_Reg(20.0))
>
> in Lin_Reg(speed)
> 1 def Lin_Reg(speed):                                             # Call the linear regression function
> 2     print(speed)
> ----> 3     speed = speed.reshape(1, -1)
> 4     lin_model_load = joblib.load("Models/lin_reg.pkl")          # Reimport the linear regression model
> 5     power_est = lin_model_load.predict(speed) # Use the linear regression model to estimate the power for the user inputted speed
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: `$('WS')` is an invalid id selector.  Id selectors start with a `#`

Comment: @Taplar: fixed that issue, but the error still persists. Edited to resolve, and show new error message.

Comment: Does "20.0" work as input value instead of "20"?

Comment: @Michiel:
Got the following error when doing that: [2020-12-30 21:15:45,215] ERROR in app: [2020-12-30 21:15:45,215] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/Lin/20.0 [GET]
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=20.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 21:15:45] "GET /api/Lin/20.0 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: I think the route is found now because you provided a float instead of a number. The new error is the `predict` method expects an array (A vector) instead of a float, but I could be wrong. Please confirm this with the documentation.

Comment: @Michiel, the line speed[0] should remove this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you send a float instead of an integer.

```
$.get('/api/Lin/' + parseFloat($('#WS').val()), function(data) {
  $('#Power_Est').val(data.value);
});
```

Also call `predict` with a 2D array.

```
power_est = np.round(lin_model_load.predict([[speed]])[0], 3)
```